CSS Z-Index - Why does a child 'absolute' element shows in the parent 'relative' element when the child element is z-index: -1?
I came across an unexpected behavior when using z-index on a child element.
To demonstrate what I mean I have used this code in https://jsfiddle.net/


<html>

<body>
  <!-- PARENT RELATIVE ELEMENT OPENS -->
  <div style="position: relative; z-index: 0; background: #ddd; width: 250px; height: 80px; padding: 10px;">RELATIVE ELEMENT
    <!-- CHILD ABSOLUTE ELEMENT OPENS -->
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px; padding: 20px; z-index: -1; background: #f55;">ABSOLUTE ELEMENT</div>
    <!-- CHILD ABSOLUTE ELEMENT CLOSED -->
  </div>
  <!-- PARENT RELATIVE ELEMENT CLOSED -->
</body>

</html>



I would expect the child element to be totally hidden as it has a z-index: -1
But what I see is the child's text and background color being displayed in the parent.
The odd thing here is that the parent's grey background color is overwritten by the child's red background but the parent's "RELATIVE ELEMENT" text is visible in the overlap.
If I remove the "z-index: 0" from the parent then the child element is hidden as expected.
I had thought that if no z-index value is stated then the element defaults to z-index: 0 so I expect the behavior to be the same with or without the z-index:0 declared in the parent.

The implicit default for z-index is not 0, but auto - and auto does not establish a new local stacking context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index#values
